# How to configure linux routing to enable load balance between two interfaces?

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking, linux-kernel, multipath

- I have these interfaces on my linux machine : eth0, vti1 and vti2.
- vti1 and vti2 were added after I configured libreswan IPSec.
  Now I want to distribute traffic through both these interfaces equally. How can I configure linux routing to achieve this?

I tried this but it did not work

- *ip route add 'DEST-CIDR' nexthop dev vti1 weight 1 nexthop dev vti2 weight 1*

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Could you please add to the question the current routing table? `ip route show` How many ISPs are you using? Do you use PI or PA classes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider-independent_address_space

Comment: @Mircea here it is :
1.)
default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100\n
2.) 10.0.0.0/16\n
        nexthop dev vti1 weight 1\n
        nexthop dev vti2 weight 1\n
3.) 172.31.32.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.36.74 metric 100\n

Comment: I am using an ec2 instance in AWS.